# React Router - Auto navigate to first nested route when visiting parent route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have nested routes.

1. `/account`  parent route
2. `/account/profile`  child route 1
3. `/account/settings` child route 2

I want to navigate to the first child route `account/profile` when users visit the parent route `/account`.

Here is my current code. Thanks in advance. :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-haze-ouxxtv?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. I just need to add another route to navigate it to the first child route.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Navigate to="account" />} />
    <Route path="account" element={<Account />}>
      <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
      <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />} />

      {/* I added this line */}
      <Route index element={<Navigate to='profile' />}></Route>

    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-haze-ouxxtv?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option using useEffect() and useNavigation(): https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-cookies-v2v4jh?file=/src/Account.js 
I think that using this way your App.js will not be overloaded.

Comment: Thanks man. This is another approach. I figured it out. I added another route.

Answer (score -1):

Copy this it will work.
thank you

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Navigate to="account" />} />
    <Route path="account" element={<Account />}>
      <Route index element={<Navigate to='profile' />} />
      <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
      <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: You didn't provide any explanation of the problem and how your comment provides the solution